# How do I create fantasy cities?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, world-building

What do I need? How do I start? etc. I want to create city states up to 1,000 years old with probably (but not necessarily) aristocratic, oligarchinc, or tyrannical (in the ancient Greece sense) governments. I'd like to do one or two possible "player bases" that would probably be more detailed, but I'd like more general tips too. I'm looking for enough information to help me make cities detailed enough for my players feel attached to the place as not just as a few more shops. I want them to care about local politics and the lower-class citizens. Someplace that is worth returning to after adventures. I don't know exactly what to ask for; that's the point.

If you need specifics, the base I'd like to make is a fortress-city as the first line of defense for other city-states. It's on the frontier by a wilderness full of creatures. It imports steel to make weapons and armor and exports wood, furs, etc.

Comment: Please specify your question (what exactly do you need to know about the city?) to get a more specific answer.

Comment: I did that purposely; I want to know what I should prepare for use with players.

Comment: For answers to be useful to your context instead of wildly guessing, we need to know *at least* what kind of story you're telling (sewer crawling, political intrigue, etc), how long the party will be in the city, and hopefully what edition of D&D you're using. The more detail you can give about your game, the more we can help. Stack Exchange isn't built to provide generic one-size-fits-all guides, we're about helping you with your specific problem in ways that others can learn from too.

Comment: If you're asking how to figure out what your city needs (as Bankuei advises), then the question should clarify that.  If you're asking how to use your RPG system to model the needs you've already defined, the question should present the needs you've identified. If you're asking how to make a city "feel real" without much concern for the RPG context you'll use it in, you might find [worldbuilding.se] a better fit.

Comment: Far too broad. This should be a couple dozen questions, not one, and only about half those questions even belong on this particular SE, with quite a few belonging on Worldbuilding, and some of them on History or Politics. What is it, *exactly*, that you want an answer to?

Comment: Regarding your edit: Those aren't the specifics that we need. We need specifics on what problem we're supposed to be solving. "I want to make cities, a fortress one. Talk to me" isn't a problem we can solve here. (A forum can help with "talk to me" questions; we can't.)

Comment: If you don't really know what to ask for, Stack Exchange isn't the tool your looking for either. We're really about concrete problems that can be well-defined, so that an answer can just solve it without having a lot of conversation. May I suggest trying a forum?

Answer (score 3):

**Flavor**

Start by thinking about what the "flavor" or general theme of the city is going to be like.  Is it high or low fantasy? Bustling, decaying, wealthy, devastated, etc.  Is it modeled after a real world culture or imagery - "Mayan cliff dwellers, but over 1,000 years of carving with magical assistance" etc.

This is mostly mental, you don't need to write pages of details, just get the idea in your head.  If you can write the flavor description in 1-3 sentences, it's best.

**Details**

With that in mind, think about the kind of game you're going to run and how the city is going to fit into it as far as what the players will be interacting with.  Are there major, recurring NPCs?  Will there be any combat/encounters in the city to where you might need a map or such?  Or can you sum everything up by just giving major landmarks a paragraph each?

If you know what kinds of things the players are probably going to interact with, you know where to focus your prep.  One sentence NPCs and general descriptions of neighborhoods/wards/sections is usually a good way to go - and you add more only where it's needed and hard to create on the fly.

Right now I'm running a game where the major city is an old city that once was the Empire's capital - now that it's been left as a simple stop along a trade route, only the old, unimportant and politically inconvenient nobles are sent there.  I've written up a bit on the major noble houses, and each has gotten an NPC with a single sentence and that's good enough.  Look at your game, your needs and prep from there.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what kind of information you expect about the city, but if you are looking for a quick and easy way, myth-weavers.com offers a very well made city generator, especially for 3.5. WotC also published a pdf that basically offered the same, but with dice roll tables instead of random automatic generation. It deals a lot with the power structure more than anything else, if I recall correctly.